# change button icon on click react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, button, icons

Using react, I have a button with an icon, a font-awsome one. I want to toggle between icon on click: the icon is an eye with a title and a boolean. If the boolean is true, the eye should be open. If the same button is clicked, the boolean turns false and the button's icon should change to close. 
My button already has a verification so it will change the icon if the boolean is true or false, my problem is on changing the boolean onClick. Tried with setState wasnt able to do so.

My button:

```
   {props.eyes.map(eye => {
                    return (<div className={"column is-2"}>
                        <button
                            className={eye.toggled === 'true' ? "button is-white fa fa-eye" : "button is-white fa fa-eye-slash"}
                            onClick={() => props.pickEye(eye)}/>
                        {eye.tituloEye}
                    </div>)
                })}
```

My state:

```
state = {

            eyes:
                [
                    {
                        toggled: 'false',
                        tituloEye: 'porta'
                    },
                    {
                        toggled: 'true',
                        tituloEye: 'prateleira'
                    },
                ],

            eyeSelecionado: '',
}
```

and Im getting the click button like:

```
pickEye = (eye) => {
    this.setState({eyeSelecionado: eye});
};
```

Comment: You are toggling your state but the state is not at all being used in your render code. Since there is no change, it will render the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set the toggled value in the parent state like

```
    {props.eyes.map((eye, index) => {
        return (<div className={"column is-2"}>
            <button
                className={eye.toggled === true 
                    ? "button is-white fa fa-ye" 
                    : "button is-white fa fa-eye-slash"
                }
                onClick={() => props.pickEye(index)}
            />
                {eye.tituloEye}
            </div>
        )
    }
)}

pickEye = (index) => {
    this.setState(prevState => ({
        var newState = {
            [index]: {
                ...prevState.eyes[index], 
                toggled: !prevState.eyes[index].toggled
            }
        };
        eyes: Object.assign([], prevState.eyes, newState)}));
};
```

Comment: Its working when going from true to false but no the other way around.

Comment: this is what I have so far, I dont know why I get no render on dom..`https://codesandbox.io/s/5zvpnn92k4`

Comment: your data should be `toggled: false,` and not `toggled: "false",` and similarly you should compare like `{eye.toggled === true ? `

Comment: No worries, glad it helped

Answer (score 0):

Your `pickEye` not need to be a listen function, because for `onClick={() => props.pickEye(index)}`, `() =>` this is already an inline listen function. And `pickEye` is your class function. So this will be `onClick={() => this.state.pickEye(index)}/>` instead of `onClick={() => props.pickEye(index)}/>`

So, change :

```
pickEye = (eye) => {
    this.setState({eyeSelecionado: eye});
}
```

To

```
pickEye(eye) {
    this.setState({eyeSelecionado: eye});
}
```

And then your button :

```
<button className={eye.toggled === 'true' ? "button is-white fa fa-eye" : "button is-white fa fa-eye-slash"}
    onClick={() => this.state.pickEye(index)}/>
```

Comment: My button is in another component then my state, thats why I used props.

Comment: So you need yo pass your `pickEye` in you child component `props`. Use `this.props` to do this. 

In your parent : `<ChildComponent pickEye ={this.pickEye} />`

And in your child component : 
`constructor(){
         this.state = { eye: this.props.eye }
    }
    componentWillReceiveProps(newProps) {
         this.setState({
             eye  : newProps.eye
         })
     }`

Comment: I wanted to avoid state in more then one component if possible

Comment: You can, but your `eye` state need to be in your Parent. When your parent `eye` state change, this will perform update `eye` props value in all childs component with `componentWillReceiveProps` . To respect React Lifecyle, see : https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#updating